# Job advert titles include "M/F"

Tags: português-europeu, abreviações

I've noticed a number of job adverts include "M/F" in their title. For example:

- [Data Scientist (M/F)](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/1612094327)
- [Novas oportunidades m/f](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/1609856534)
- [Mercado Empresarial de energia - Lisboa B2B (m/f)](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/1609803664)

What does the "M/F" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The job ads are from companies in Portugal and in Portugal it is an obligatory measure to avoid benefits/discrimination, specially gender related, as the "M/F" come from the words:

M - Masculino (*Male*)

F - Feminino (*Female*)

The Código do Trabalho (*Labor Code*) approved by Lay n.º 7/2009 (12 February) states that, specifically the Artigo 24.º ([read it here](https://dre.pt/application/conteudo/602073)):

> **Artigo 24.º**
>
> **Direito à igualdade no acesso a emprego e no trabalho**
>
> 1 — O trabalhador ou candidato a emprego tem direito a **igualdade de
> oportunidades e de tratamento** no que se refere ao acesso ao emprego, à
> formação e promoção ou carreira profissionais e às condições de
> trabalho, **não podendo ser privilegiado, beneficiado, prejudicado,
> privado de qualquer direito ou isento de qualquer dever em razão**,
> nomeadamente, de ascendência, idade, sexo, orientação sexual, estado
> civil, situação familiar, situação económica, instrução, origem ou
> condição social, património genético, capacidade de trabalho reduzida,
> deficiência, doença crónica, nacionalidade, origem étnica ou raça,
> território de origem, língua, religião, convicções políticas ou
> ideológicas e filiação sindical, devendo o Estado promover a igualdade
> de acesso a tais direitos

Apart from that, as we are talking about an opening advert, the Artigo 30.º, states the following:

> 2 — O anúncio de oferta de emprego e outra forma de publicidade ligada
> à pré -selecção ou ao recrutamento **não pode conter, directa ou
> indirectamente, qualquer restrição, especificação ou preferência
> baseada no sexo.**

Although the legislation expressly condemns any discriminatory practice, there are still lots of job ads that don't follow the standards. Comissão para a Igualdade no Trabalho e no Emprego (CITE) [states some examples of those descriminations](http://cite.gov.pt/pt/acite/anuncios.html):

> - anúncios dirigidos diretamente a um dos sexos;
> - anúncios que não informam de forma visível e clara que a oferta é destinada a trabalhadores e trabalhadoras (M/F);
> - anúncios que, apesar de indicarem a sigla M/F, contêm elementos claramente indiciadores de preferência por um dos sexos.

Comment: Is it also related to the fact that when describing a job title in portuguese it is always generdised? While in English this is not always the case.

Comment: Can you give me an example @joshlk?

Answer (score 4):

It means

M - Pessoa do sexo Masculino (*Male person*)

F - Pessoa do sexo Feminino (*Feminine person*)

To include all kind of people and avoid any discrimination, the companies use these acronym to stay clear that does not matter the gender.

Others acronyms:

D - pessoas portadoras de Deficiência (*handicapped*)

V - pessoas com muita experiência ou idade – Veterano (*Senior professional or elderly*)

X - pessoas que se identificam como masculinas ou femininas (*trans person*)

Source: [Feed Empregos](http://feedempregos.blogspot.com/2018/12/as-siglas-nos-anuncios-de-emprego.html)

Comment: You should explain that "M/F" means either gender is acceptable, as opposed e.g. to «Assistente de loja (F)» or «Segurança (M)» where only one of the genders is expected or accepted (‍♀️).

Comment: What is strange is that for me, you cannot discriminate any gender or situation... So, these acronyms in the end, no make sense...

Comment: You could have an advertisement for women only, for working in a gynecologist office or in a bra shop or in a safe-house for women victims of domestic abuse; or one for men only, for working in a male underwear shop. These would not be, in my honest opinion, discriminatory job postings. But in almost all situations, yes, I agree with you that they would be discriminatory. Men can work as hairdressers or cleaners, women can work as drivers or doorman (heh).

Comment: Nunca vi "V" sendo usado para indicar um grupo de pessoas.  Seria um acrônimo para "velhos" ?  Em pt-BR dizemos "idosos" ou "terceira idade", não "velhos".

Comment: V quer dizer (V)eterano...

Comment: Peixoto, queres expandir a tua resposta? Descobri isto da Comissão para a Igualdade no Trabalho e no Emprego, que cita a lei em concreto de 2009 e tudo: http://cite.gov.pt/pt/acite/anuncios.html

Answer (score 3):

I believe they mean "male or female" though it may be somewhat unclear in Portuguese. It would sound more natural if they had written "ambos os sexos".  It's very common to write M or F in English, as in SWM (single white male) or SWF (single white female) but not in Portuguese, where "H ou M" (homem ou mulher) is expected. Maybe it was written by an English-speaking person.

Acredito tratar-se de "masculino" e "feminino" embora ficasse mais claro escrever por extenso ou substituir por "ambos os sexos".  Como trata-se de oportunidades de emprego, talvez o autor esteja usando o que considera ser termos que abraçam todas as ideologias de gênero ou então... trata-se de um falante da língua inglesa.

Comment: Tens razão, é isso. Mas não tem a ver com ideologias de género, é uma cena antiga já.

Comment: But, hmm, in Portugal it doesn't look or sound awkward. Outdated, only.

Comment: @ANeves    You're right, not exactly awkward but unclear to some people.